# IntegrityError at /products/new/ NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.user_id

Tags: django

I am creating a marketplace where selected users can have their shop and CRUD their products.
I am running an error when creating the Createview class. I need the form where user adds a new product, returns his own shop name based on the shop model, but looks like there is an error as above.
Following is my app:

models.py

```
class Shop(models.Model):

    shop_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    owner    = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name

class Product(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    shop            = models.ForeignKey (Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shop')
    category        = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name ='Categoria',on_delete=False )
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank= True, null=True, unique = True)
```

views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,SubmitBtnMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = '/products/list'
    submit_btn = 'Add Product'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_product = form.save(commit=False)
        user = self.request.user
        s = Shop.objects.get (owner=user)
        new_product.shop = s
        new_product.save()
        return super (ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

FORM.PY

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'image']
        exclude = ['shop']
```

Comment: You forgot to add a user to your model. `new_product.user = user` before you `new_product.save()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Product model I don't see an attribute 'description', but in your form you have specified a field 'description'. Try adding null=True, blank=True to the user field in your Product model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey (Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shop')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name ='Categoria',on_delete=False )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank= True, null=True, unique = True)
```

Comment: Hi, yeah pasting I truncated some of  my model fields as the issue was surely in the first rows. After your suggestion now it works..will this change (null=True, blank=True ) affect the user model function in any case? thanks